# Session only works 99% of the time

Tags: php, session

I'm taking another stab at a problem that's plagued me for years.  I use sessions for logged in users, as one does. For new users I create a new db entry and then retrieve the newly-created UserID key, and for existing ones I retrieve that key from the table. In either case I catch if the read/write errors so I know I have $UserID set by the time I get to the next code section. Which is simply this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['User'] = $UserID;

/* Proceed to next page */
```

When I go to that next page, the first thing I do is:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) kickoutTo("SessionCheck.php");
```

And what drives me nuts is that maybe 1% of the time, I get that redirect.  (SessionCheck.php is a page I made specifically for this problem, to gather feedback from these unlucky users.)

Now I can only imagine two reasons a session wouldn't be created:

1. They don't accept cookies.
2. A write issue on the drive won't create the temp file.

So my catch page writes a test cookie and then reads it on a followup page.  The vast majority have no problem accepting them. (And the ones that do are informed as such.)  So I don't think the issue is the acceptance of cookies. (Unless browsers have some way of only rejecting sessionid ones?  I don't know, just spitballing.)

And for the second issue, if the drive couldn't write I'm sure it would cause a bunch of problems for everyone at once. I've had this happen a time or two over the years when a backup process goes awry; I just yell at my hosts and its resolved.

So I can't explain why most people have no problem but just a few do. For example, I've logged into my own site many thousands of times and never experienced it. But I get hundreds of logs from people who do. They're all using different browsers and different OS. They're on IPs from all over the world. It can happen 1 at a time or in clumps.  Most of the errors come from new users, but not always.

Here are my session settings from phpinfo:

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  10000   10000
session.gc_maxlifetime  18000   18000
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

What could be doing this? Where do I look? What can I test for?  It's been happening for years and during that time I've even changed servers within the same host company.  Many thanks with this puzzle.

Comment: Maybe they open the page, let it sit for 30 minutes, then click a link, and get redirected to the login page because session expired. Users typically don't understand that sessions expire if you just leave the page sitting and aren't navigating.

Comment: cache expire is set to 3 hours... session cache is invalid after 3 hours so they get booted out. Change the value in php.ini and restart apache/fpm.

Comment: Well I also do garbage cleanup ever 8 hours and manually require login after 6, but this is not an issue of a successful session that needs to be expired.  It happens immediately with no user interaction. The login page processes them, and then directly redirects to a welcome page which can't identify their session. This is a second apart.  So I'll improve that cache time but I don't think it's related.